# Computing childrens of ith node of a d-ary tree

Tags: data-structures, trees, mathematical-analysis

Assume that we represent a complete d-ary tree in an array[1,...n] (this is a 1-based array of size n).

The formula for indices of children of node no. i is given as:

{(1-i)d+2,
... , min{n,(1-i)d+d+1}}

I am not able to get the intuition to arrive at this formula.
Can someone please help ?

Comment: How are the nodes of the tree ordered in the array? DFS? BFS?

Comment: @6005 the nodes are ordered in BFS

Answer (score 1):

The (traditional) binary heap (as e.g. in [heapsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort)) is exactly your case, with $d = 2$; for 0-based arrays the children of $k$ are at $2 k + 1$ and $2 k + 2$. Analogously, in your case the children of $k$ are at $d k + 1, d k + 2, \dotsc, d k + d$.

The children of $0$ are at $1, 2, \dotsc, d$; children of $1$ start after that ($d + 1, d + 2, \dotsc, 2 d$), children of $2$ are at $2 d + 1, \dotsc, 3 d$, and so on. You should see the pattern here.